# Solve the differential equation $4y=x^2+(y')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $4y=x^2+(y')^2$.

My try:
$$4 y'=2x+2y'y''$$ hence $2y'=x+y'y''$. Let $y'=vx$, then $y''=v+xv'$, hence
$$2vx=x+vx(v+xv')$$
$$-\int {v\over (v-1)^2} dv=\int {1\over x} dx$$
For R.H.S. Let $u=v-1$
So :
$${1\over u}-\ln u=\ln x+c$$
$${1\over {v-1}}-\ln |v-1|=\ln |x|+c$$
By substitute $v={y'\over x}$ :
$${x\over {y'-x}}-\ln \left|{{y'-x}\over x}\right|=\ln |x| +c$$
that is:
$${x\over {y'-x}}-\ln \left|y'-x\right|=c$$
True ?

Comment: What is $P$? $ $

Comment: $P={dy\over dx}$

Comment: I rewrote partially your post, please try to emulate the result for your next questions...

Comment: Thank you so much , but it's true answer or not?

Comment: The manipulations seem correct but they do not yield the solution, right?

Comment: I am so sorry, I don't speak English well, can you explain?

Comment: Explain what? If you mean "provide a full solution asap plz thx" then no I will not do that.

Comment: @Dima Have you tried plugging in your answer back into the differential equation?  That is a good way to check if you made a mistake.

Comment: No no, I mean please explain by "yes or no" my answer is correct or no? Because I don't speak English well, Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron thanks I will br try.

Comment: You are only transforming an ODE to another ODE, not really solve the ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4y=x^2+(y')^2$

$\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=4y-x^2$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{4y-x^2}$

Let $u=\pm\sqrt{4y-x^2}$ ,

Then $y=\dfrac{u^2+x^2}{4}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{u}{2}\dfrac{du}{dx}+\dfrac{x}{2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{u}{2}\dfrac{du}{dx}+\dfrac{x}{2}=u$

$\dfrac{u}{2}\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{2u-x}{2}$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=2-\dfrac{x}{u}$

Let $v=\dfrac{u}{x}$ ,

Then $u=xv$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=x\dfrac{dv}{dx}+v$

$\therefore x\dfrac{dv}{dx}+v=2-\dfrac{1}{v}$

$x\dfrac{dv}{dx}=-v+2-\dfrac{1}{v}$

$x\dfrac{dv}{dx}=-\dfrac{v^2-2v+1}{v}$

$x\dfrac{dv}{dx}=-\dfrac{(v-1)^2}{v}$

$\dfrac{v}{(v-1)^2}~dv=-\dfrac{dx}{x}$

$\int\dfrac{v}{(v-1)^2}~dv=-\int\dfrac{dx}{x}$

$\ln(v-1)-\dfrac{1}{v-1}=-\ln x+c$

$(v-1)e^{-\frac{1}{v-1}}=\dfrac{C_1}{x}$

$\left(\dfrac{u}{x}-1\right)e^{-\frac{1}{\frac{u}{x}-1}}=\dfrac{C_1}{x}$

$(u-x)e^\frac{x}{x-u}=C_1$

$(\pm\sqrt{4y-x^2}-x)e^\frac{x}{x\mp\sqrt{4y-x^2}}=C_1$

$(x\pm\sqrt{4y-x^2})e^\frac{x}{x\pm\sqrt{4y-x^2}}=C$